# how to judge the last index(varStatus) via EL expression

Tags: jsp, el

```
<c:forEach items="${orderTable.dtoPassengers}" var="passengerVar" varStatus="passengerStatus">
        <c:if test="${passengerStatus.index == last}">${passengerVar.passengerName}</c:if>
        <c:if test="${passengerStatus.index != last}">${passengerVar.passengerName}/</c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

**i just want to judge the index(varStatus) is last one, how can i do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `first` and `last` properties of varStatus:

http://www.bmchild.com/2012/03/jstl-cforeach-varstatus-properties.html